# python3 counting values for each key in a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this:

```
{a: [a, s, d, f], b: [d, f, g, h, j], ...}
```

I want an output that shows me a dictionary of a key and counts the values in the list. It should look like this:

```
{a: 4, b: 5, ...}
```

Anyone knows?

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know how to find the length of a list? Do you know how to iterate over key-value pairs of a dict?

Comment: I know how to use len(). The question is how to direct it to the list of values in each K,V pairs

Comment: @DeepSpace I search google for answer but didn't find because I don't always know the right terminology to use in search. Thanks for helping beginner with such kindness :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by this way:

```
for key, value in dict.items():
    # print(key, len([item for item in value if item]))
     print(key, len(value))
```

Comment: Why `len([item for item in value if item])` ? You already have a list. `len(value)`

Comment: @DeepSpace thanks for your comment, yes that can also be done, updated

Answer (score 1):

you can construct the output `dict` using the following code:

```
dict_2= { a:len(b) for a,b in dict_1.items()}
print(dict_2)
>>> {'a': 4, 'b': 5}
```

where `dict_1` is the input `dict`.